# tailwindcss: How to hide and show (toggle) html elements with media queries on browser resizes?

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

tailwindcss media queries are mobile first, thus said I am trying to activate html elements for each level of my media queries.

Here is what I got, which does not work when I resize the browser window:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <span class="m-1 hidden xl:inline">
      XL
    </span>
    <span class="m-1 hidden lg:inline xl:hidden">
      L
    </span>
    <span class="m-1 hidden md:inline lg:hidden">
      M
    </span>
    <span class="m-1 hidden sm:inline md:hidden">
      S
    </span>
    <span class="m-1 inline sm:hidden">
      XS
    </span>
  </div>
</template>
```

Do I have a logic error on how media-queries work in tailwind?

Or maybe the hard part is to overwrite `display: none;` if it is once set? (Then I guess it is a css problem) XS seems to be working.

Comment: working fine - https://play.tailwindcss.com/j92lMBV4U5

Comment: Dang ok thanks! I thought it was working, but I guess my js setup is messing with the classes.

Comment: I find `npm run watch` fixes most problems associated with tailwindcss. It ensures tailwind rebuilds every time there are changes in your file

Comment: I am using yarn ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried your example, and it works perfectly for me in tailwind playground when i resize the window. Are you sure the classes got through the build process? You want to show one text at a time, when u resize the window. One for each breakpoint, if i got it right.

Comment: yes that is correct. Can you send me the link to the tailwind playground? maybe my nuxtjs environment is messing with tailwind ...

Comment: https://play.tailwindcss.com/